# Displaying blog posts in an RSS feed based on keywords in the title

Tags: javascript, html, web, rss, feed

I'm currently in the process of creating a site for a client. I'm trying to remove myself from the site as much as possible as I will not always be on call to update the site. Using RSS feeds as a tool, I'm planning on have them post to Blogger and have that feed to the site.

The problem is there are multiple things they will be posting about and each of these will be on different pages.

Is there anyway to parse the data so that only certain posts with keywords will show up on one feed and posts with other words will show up on the other feeds? I'm trying to reduce the amount of work into one account and one blog.

For instance, a blog title will read "Agenda for April 24, 2014" and because the word 'agenda' is read in, it will post to the RSS feed on 'agenda.html'. Or another title could read "News Blast on April 24, 2014" and it would post to the RSS feed on 'news.html'.

Is this possible? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

May be there is a way using `Label` to posts you add.. if its about Movie add Movies as Label.. so that you can categories your posts depending upon labels and also be viewed using  different pages for a particular label